# Reativar ultimo app que ficou em background (Android)

Tags: java, android, background, android-intent

No android ao apertar duas vezes seguidas o botão de atividade (botão quadrado), ele alterna entre a aplicativo aberto e o aplicativo que estava ativo antes do atual.
Gostaria de realizar isso via codigo, ou seja, ***chamar de volta o aplicativo no background que estava aberto antes do atual***.
Li sobre Intents mais não conseguir formular um meio de obter o resultado que desejo.
Desde já grato a quem puder ajudar !!!

Comment: Você pode usar [ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningAppProcesses()) para capturar todos apps que estão abertos e usar Intents para abri-los

Comment: Eu li bastante sobre isso para detectar se o app esta em primeiro plano, bastaria eu usar o IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND para o que desejo, porem foi descontinuado na API 26. Estou tentando usar o RecentTaskInfo porem, sem sucesso, por enquanto,,,

Comment: RecentTaskInfo também foi descontinuado... Vou tentar com AppTask. Provisoriamente estou usando serviço de acessibilidade para enviar 2 GLOBAL_ACTION_RECENTS

Answer (score 0):

Muito obrigado a todos que ajudaram, após muitas pesquisas e testes, consegui o resultado desejado, na verdade melhor que o esperado, pois ele busca o contexto e reabre o app que chamou o app atual na hora que for executado, sendo assim mesmo que eu abra um terceiro app manualmente ele me retorna para o primeiro app (no caso o meu app). Vou deixar o código para que futuramente possa ajudar quem necessitar fazer o mesmo, é necessario SDK >= 21:

```html
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasksList = am.getAppTasks();
for (ActivityManager.AppTask task : tasksList){
task.moveToFront();
}
```